# Pandas agg and listagg at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I want to `AGG` operations on column `B` and `C`, while using `LISTAGG` on column `D`.

Currently I do `groupby` twice - once for `LISTAGG` and once for `AGG` - aftewards I join the two resulting dataframes.

I was wondering if it is possible to do both `LISTAGG` and `AGG` operations in the same `groupby` call?

Minimal Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'A' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
                  , 'B' : [10, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 14]
                  , 'C' : [22, 20, 8, 10, 13, 10, 0]
                  , 'D' : ['x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'v', 'k' ]
                  })
print(df)

df_listagg = df.groupby(['A'])['D'].apply(list).reset_index(name='D_listagg')
print(df_listagg)

df_agg = df.groupby(['A']).agg({'B': 'sum', 'C': 'min'}).reset_index()
print(df_agg)

df_result = pd.merge(df_listagg, df_agg, on=['A'], how='left')
print(df_result)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
   A     D_listagg   B   C
0  1  [x, y, y, z]  43   8
1  2        [w, v]  23  10
2  3           [k]  14   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply include 'D' column in the aggrigration:

```
df=df.groupby('A',as_index=False).agg({'B': 'sum', 'C': 'min','D':list})
```

output of df:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   43  8   [x, y, y, z]
1   2   23  10  [w, v]
2   3   14  0   [k]
```

Comment: You can actually pass any function to agg, output will be the agg :)